# What is B. D. Ripley's method of seeding the Mersenne-Twister RNG?

Tags: random-generation

R's documentation behind `?runif` states that the default RNG is

> "Mersenne-Twister": From Matsumoto and Nishimura (1998); code updated
> in 2002. A twisted GFSR with period 2^19937 - 1 and equidistribution
> in 623 consecutive dimensions (over the whole period). The ‘seed’ is a
> 624-dimensional set of 32-bit integers plus a current position in that
> set.
>
> R uses its own initialization method due to B. D. Ripley and is not
> affected by the initialization issue in the 1998 code of Matsumoto and
> Nishimura addressed in a 2002 update.

I would like to read about R's initialization method due to B. D. Ripley but there is no reference to a particular paper or chapter in a book. I would appreciate someone describing - or pointing me to a reference that would describe - B. D. Ripley's method of seeding the Mersenne-Twister RNG.

link to source code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/452e284fe7c76ee25f5cac36614f79758546c051/src/main/RNG.c#L266)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if it's documented except in the code (`src/main/RNG.c`)

```
static void RNG_Init(RNGtype kind, Int32 seed)
{
    int j;

    BM_norm_keep = 0.0; /* zap Box-Muller history */

    /* Initial scrambling */
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        seed = (69069 * seed + 1);
    switch (kind) {
    case WICHMANN_HILL:
    case MARSAGLIA_MULTICARRY:
    case SUPER_DUPER:
    case MERSENNE_TWISTER:
    /* i_seed[0] is mti, *but* this is needed for historical consistency */
    for (j = 0; j < RNG_Table[kind].n_seed; j++) {
        seed = (69069 * seed + 1);
        RNG_Table[kind].i_seed[j] = seed;
    }
    FixupSeeds(kind, 1);
    /* snippety snip */
}
```

That is, the initialisation works by running a linear congruential generator $x\mapsto 69069\cdot x+1$ for 50 iterations, then enough iterations to fill up the seed, then imposing any constraints needed by the specific generator.  This makes sure any user-supplied seeds (often small integers) end up spread across the seed space of the generator.

This congruential generator is due to Marsaglia, and Prof Ripley used and recommended it as a pseudorandom number source back in the days when the demand for random numbers was low enough for its period to be sufficient.

Comment: +1 I doubt there's much more to be said. Maybe, something could be dug up in the R devel mailing list about it, but I guess that if there was something worth mentioning it would be in the docs or at least as a comment in the source code.

Comment: From a C code point of view, if Int32 is signed as the name suggests, this code has *undefined behavior* (a bad thing) because of signed integer overflow in the LCG.

Comment: I would also like to note that this hasn't been a "fun" change. If anything it made R's random number initialisation different from C/Python/MATLAB's and pretty much ensured that getting reproducibility with the other languages is *very hard*.

Comment: R has undefined behaviour in a number of other ways. For example, it fundamentally assumes a particular memory format for the `double` type. Anyway, if someone wants to ask a completely different question about why this method was chosen in and why Python compatibility wasn't considered, they could do that.

Comment: I did ask about this years ago a R core dev I was in the same Stats department with and his answer was "Meh..." If anything he seemed somewhat surprised the other languages agreed with C. And I think it is unreasonable to ask why R didn't consider compatibility with Python or any other language that was also in its infancy when R came around (early 90's).